# error response from the linkedin using rest api

Tags: angular, ionic2, linkedin-api, mean-stack

I'm trying to implement the sign-in LinkedIn functionality using rest API method. I've got the `access_token` & `expires_in`from the LinkedIn. I've extracted the access_token from it & passed to the `get` request to get the profile details. But I'm not getting any response in return. This is my code.

```
gettheLinkedinUserDetails(token: any) {

alert(token);

let headers = new HttpHeaders();

//headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

headers.append('Authorization','Bearer '+token);

return this.http.get('https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,email-address,picture-url)?format=json',{headers: headers})

}
```

&

```
this.lkPage.gettheLinkedinUserDetails(result)
            .subscribe((profileData: any) => {
              alert(profileData + 'profile');
            },(err) => {
              alert(err + 'error');
            })
```

& in the response, I'm getting the error as
`{"headers":{"nomalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null},"status":401,"stsusText":"OK","url":"https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,email-address,picture-url?format=json"
","ok":false,"name":"httpErrorResponse""message":"Http failure response forhttps://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,email-address,picture-url)?format=json;401 OK","error
":{"errorCode":0,"message":"Unknown authentication schema","requestId":"B6AFJPFBMX","status":401
"timestamp":1535978521964}}`

Comment: Do you subscribe to `gettheLinkedinUserDetails()` anywhere in your code?

Comment: yes I've. `this.lkPage.gettheLinkedinUserDetails(result)
            .subscribe((profileData: any) => {
              alert(profileData + 'profile');
            },(err) => {
              alert(err + 'error');
            })`
& in the response I'm getting `[object object error]`